# update data in a many to many releationship by spring-boot-jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a many to many relationship. Task2Group.

I'm trying to update some base info of a task using the save() method of spring-boot-jpa.
But when I do not set the groupSet of the task I try to update, and save it, the old task2group relationship will be removed.

I know reason but I just wanna konw how to update the task entity without geting the GroupSet and then set it.

Here are the Task entity related to group

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinTable(name = "task_2_group", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"))
private Set<Group> groupSet;
```

and here are the group

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groupSet")
private Set<Task> taskSet;
```

Comment: show the method in which you retrieve and save

Comment: Just the default usage of spring-boot-jpa, like taskDao.save(task)

Comment: ok but how do you retreive Task? also do you manipulate the Set after retrieval?